# Adding Lua Function Syntax

Tags: scripting, syntax, lua

I'm working on a MUD using C++ and Lua, and I'm trying to create a set of functions for emotes.

I've written:

```
add_functions
{
   ['subject-bind-search say'] = 'none',
   ['player say string-type'] = function(player, msg)
      player_text(player, 'You say "' .. msg.string .. '".')
      witness_text(player, M('indefinite', player) .. ' says "' .. msg.string .. '".')
   end,
   ['subject-bind-search say-to'] = 'none',
   ['player say-to string-type thing'] = function(player, msg, thing)
      player_text(player, 'You say "' .. msg.string .. '" to ' .. M('definite',thing) .. '.')
      witness_text(player, M('indefinite', player) .. ' says "' .. msg.string .. '" to ' .. M('indefinite', thing) .. '.')
      end,
      ['player dance'] = function(player)
        player_text(player, 'You burst into dance.')
        witness_text(player, M('indefinite', player)..' bursts into dance.')
        add_atoms{dance='verb'}
        end 
}
```

When I and others connect to the server with telnet, I can type:

> say "hi" --> everyone sees hi as desired.

I can type:

> say "hi" to playerBob --> playerBob sees hi just fine

However, if I type simply: `dance`
I get an error message that is sent when it cannot recognize any verbs.
I had presumed `add_atoms{ dance = 'verb' }` fixed that, and yet...

Does anyone happen to know why I'm unable to get dancing to happen?

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

"add_atoms { dance = 'verb' }" doesn't go in the add_functions code. 
It has to be made, or at least can be, outside of the add_functions method.
Like so:

```
add_atoms{[{'say', 'dance', 'apologize', 'bark', 'flex'}]='verb', to='preposition'}

add_functions
{
...
}
```

Comment: If you've figured out your problem, you can mark your own answer as the correct one.

Comment: Yeah.
It's making me wait until tomorrow before it will accept me marking it as correct. But I would like to.